# Linearlayout above Relativelayout ( gravity bottom )

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

**Layout wrap content not working**

Below is my XML code . I want to place the portion linear layout with grey colour just above the main image . [Screenshot of my code here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yp7Gv.jpg).

In devices with aspect ratio 16:9 design is correct , but in 18:9 and 18.5:9 the grey portion is on top side .

The topic text and icon must be top left side portion of main image .

[The design i want here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3pcQJ.jpg)

Never mind top side . From bottom the hight must be wrap the size of image

```
    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@color/light_green"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@color/dark_green">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/topLin"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@color/grey"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/nameTxt"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:gravity="center|start"
                android:maxLength="25"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="Abin Stanly"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:src="@drawable/test" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignTop="@id/imageView"
                android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/icon"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/icon_height"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/icon_height"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_love" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/topicTxt"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:paddingEnd="10dp"
                    android:shadowColor="@color/grey"
                    android:shadowDx=".5"
                    android:shadowDy=".5"
                    android:shadowRadius="3.5"
                    android:text="Topic"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />


            </LinearLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: remove `android:gravity="center"` from your linear layout

Comment: You need to strip down on your layouts. Rather use `ContraintLayout`, `FrameLayout` or `RelativeLayout`. You will then be able to use `android:layout_topOf="@id/parentLinear"` https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/

Comment: @KaranMer all gravity is removed . no use

Comment: your imageview height is wrapcontent, set it to match_parent.

Comment: @AbinStanly could you please provide the exact UI that you need?

Comment: @KaranMer if i set imageview height to match parent , there will be space in imageview (not adding scaletype to image view ) and the love icon and Topic text will be on that portion . i want to put love icon and text at top left of image in imageview

Comment: @ManishJain attached url of design. pleace check

Comment: @AbinStanly issue fixed?

Comment: @JinsLukose No . For the time being  programmitticaly set the position by getting the device height and width .

Answer (score 0):

Here the main layout is `RelativeLayout` and the children are both `layout_alignParentBottom="true"`

You can just switch the child layouts around until you get the required layout

Tip: The less layouts you use, the faster rendering will be on slow devices.

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/light_green">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@color/grey">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/nameTxt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:gravity="center|start"
            android:maxLength="25"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="Abin Stanly"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/icon"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/icon_height"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/icon_height"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_love" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip :) . But where is the imageview layout in answer .

Answer (score 0):

I have added `weightSum` to parent `LinearLayout` so you can easily divide screen according to your requirements.

Assigned `View`  `android:layout_weight="3"` so it will cover 3/10th part of the screen, you can change it according to what you feels good for you.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="10"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="3" 
            android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
            />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="7">



            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/nameTxt"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:maxLength="25"
                android:padding="11dp"
                android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
                android:text="Abin Stanly"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_below="@+id/nameTxt"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"

                >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:src="@drawable/mobile_world" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignTop="@id/imageView"
                    android:background="@android:color/black"
                    android:padding="11dp"
                    >

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/icon"
                        android:layout_width="30dp"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:src="@drawable/back_arrow" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/topicTxt"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:paddingEnd="10dp"
                        android:shadowColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
                        android:shadowDx=".5"
                        android:shadowDy=".5"
                        android:shadowRadius="3.5"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:text="Topic"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />


                </LinearLayout>

            </RelativeLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

**Output**

[image: Output Image]

Comment: Dont add scale type , because i want to show orginal image size . and i want to attach icon and text  on image not above it like this https://imgur.com/a/UgruxgQ . Never mind top side . from bottom the hight must be wrap the wize of image

Comment: devices with different resolution (like more width ) image will be in left side with gap in right side

Comment: That's why i added scale type `android:scaleType="centerCrop"`. either you should use that or `android:scaleType="fitXY"`

Comment: some images contains text from left end. if scaletype is centercrop or fitxy , it will cut

Answer (score 0):

> Check this layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nameTxt"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/imageView"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:maxLength="25"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="Abin Stanly"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textStyle="bold" />


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/test" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/topicTxt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_love"
        android:drawablePadding="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingEnd="10dp"
        android:shadowColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:shadowDx=".5"
        android:shadowDy=".5"
        android:shadowRadius="3.5"
        android:text="Topic"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: some images contains text from left end. if scaletype is centercrop or fitxy , it will cut .devices with different resolution (like more width ) image will be in left side with gap in right side